# Is Moles Framework supported in visual studio 2019? If yes how to set it up?

Tags: c#, nunit, moles

Recently I started writing Nunit code for unit testing my MVC c# code. So I am facing the difficulty to mock static classes and methods.
Is Moles Framework supported in visual studio 2019? If yes how to set it up?

Comment: Moles was discontinued 10 years ago. Why do you want to use *that* for mocking instead of eg Moq or any of the many open source mocking libraries? Are you following some old tutorial perhaps? As for mocking static classes - don't use static classes if you want to mock them in the first place. There are ways to mock them (especially if you use a commercial tool like JustMock) but they aren't trivial

Comment: In any case, Moles was replaced by [Fakes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/isolating-code-under-test-with-microsoft-fakes?view=vs-2022) which is part of Visual Studio Enterprise so not free either. In the linked page, a shim is used to mock `DateTime.Now`